# WebEssentials 2013 has stopped creating css files from less files

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2 with visual studio 2013.

for some reason it's stopped creating css files when I'm creating/saving less files.

what can be the issue ? I tried looking at the Web Essentials settings but didn't find something that can help bring back making css files when saving a less file

Answer (score 0):

Check Tools > Options > Web Essentials > Less

Compile files on save = true